# SQL Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date SQL Server cannot change date type format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have taken a random table here. In my original table there are 70,000 rows and I cannot change each one's date format indiviudally. So please dont suggest me to change date formats. Please tell me how to work with this kind of data?
Many answers i read told to change date format to yyyy-mm-dd . Please note that **I cannot change format of date in my original table**

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Emp_demo3 ( emp_ID INT,  emp_Name NVARCHAR (50),
                emp_sal_K INT,emp_manager INT,joining_date date,
                last_time date) 
            GO

            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (1,'Ali', 200,2,'2010-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770,4,'2008-01-28','2015-05-09')
```

**Code**

```
alter table emp_demo3
add date_diff1 date
go
update emp_demo3 set date_diff1 = datediff(day,joining_date, last_time)
```

**Error**

```
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem... You defined `date_diff1` as a `date`, but `DATEDIFF` returns an `int`.

Comment: ALTER TABLE EMP_DEMO3
        ADD DATE_DIFF1 AS DATEDIFF(DAY,JOINING_DATE, LAST_TIME)
        GO

You can use this @ShailajaGuptaKapoor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your alter code with the following

```
alter table emp_demo3
add date_diff1 int
go
update emp_demo3 set date_diff1 = datediff(day,joining_date, last_time)
```

Comment: ya actually so doesnt allow to accept before 9minutes...have liked but not able to accept...waiting for 5 more minutes'

Answer (score 2):

As the commenter points out, the error you're having is explaining the problem. DATEDIFF is a method that returns an integer count of `datepart` that between the second and third parameters.

[Documentation Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You should define `date_diff1` as an integer.

```sql
alter table emp_demo3
add date_diff1 int
go
update emp_demo3 set date_diff1 = datediff(day,joining_date, last_time)
```